# Datetime function returning an error using datetime.strptime()

Tags: python-3.x

Can't figure out why its returning an error when I have year - month - date in the correct order

```
from datetime import datetime

dates = ['2017  May  12th' ,'2016  December  22nd' ,'2016  Novermber  17th' 
         ,'2016  November  3rd' ,'2016  November  17th' ,'2017  May  12th'
         ,'2017  December  22nd' ,'2017  November  17th' ,'2017  November  3rd' ,
         '2017  November  17th' ,'2017  May  12th' ,'2018  December  22nd' ,'2018  November  17th' 
         ,'2018  November  3rd' ,'2018  November  17th' ,'2019  May  12th' ,'2019  December  22nd' ,
         '2019  November  17th' ,'2019  November  3rd' ,'2019  November  17th' ,'2020  October  31st']

dates.sort(key = lambda dates: datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y  %b  %d'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, as a potential contributor (You), I suggest that try to figure out simple problems like this (For your own sake) on your own. That will help you get better understanding of how the code works and will make you a better problem solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the statement `datetime.striptime(dates, '%Y %b %d')` throws an error because it can't interpret the day correctly.  To fix this problem easily, I would do the following:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

dates.sort(key = lambda dates: parser.parse(dates))
```